# What will happen with pregnant free slave?

Tags: sharia, women, slavery

If a person free his slave while his slave was pregnant who will take custody of child. Mother? or her Owner who free him?

Comment: Who is the supposed father of the child? A slave or a free man?

Comment: The father of the child is the free person.

Comment: With this i think you will understand it clearly. Let’s suppose i have a women slave and i done intercourse with him and then i free him. Now if she get’s pregnant after become free women because i done intercourse with him so now the child is mine? or not? in sharia law

Comment: You should edit your post and add this information. Further it could be good to know whether the owner knew about the pregnancy...

Comment: Who else would the child be of? If the man is the father through a legal relationship, he is the father and takes the rights of the father

Comment: If an owner has sexual relations with his slave and then frees her, then the slave must first observe a waiting period called istibra'.  For a pregnant slave this will end after the pregnancy ends. If a child is born then obviously their legal father will be their biological father (i.e. the master), and their legal mother would be their biological mother (the now freed slave). And the rights and obligations of each apply.

Comment: Ok thanks that’s helpful